# Check if an address needs storage paid

Tags: storage

What's the quickest way through RPC call to check if an address need 0.257 xtz burnt in order to pay for storage?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the balance is exactly 0, then it needs the burn.
`/chains/main/blocks/head/context/contracts/${addr}/balance`

Comment: Do I need to check also if it's been at least a cycle with balance 0? Or is it immediately inactive and needs the burn?

Comment: According to the other question you asked, immediately inactive. You can test this by using the `tezos-client` in `--dry-run` mode and see if the client adds an additional fee.

Comment: If the balance is exactly 0 AND it's not a delegate and not a `KT` address ;)